# How to read unicode from a file and display the data in a QTextEdit?

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qtcore, qfile

I want to read unicode from file and display the corresponding data in a QTextEdit.Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: You are welcome to ask, but please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Please provide us with more information so that we can tell you what's wrong in your program. Show us some parts of your code will be helpful

Comment: I am unable to copy code,could you tell me how to copy my code here??

Comment: You shall not copy code if it is not a one liner into comments, but you can update your question... Anyway, my code works, so you could just take it as is.

Comment: Yes,your code absolutely works fine for file contains normal data i.e english characters(eg:Hello),but what actually i need is i should get equvalent data from unicode characters(\u0c38\u0c60\u0c30\u0c31\u0c33\u0c2f\u0c38\u0c60\u0c30\u0c31\u0c33\u0c2f).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit poor, but you need to use QFile and QTextEdit for this as follows:

```
QFile file("in.txt");
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    return;

QTextStream in(&file);
while (!in.atEnd())
    myTextEdit.append(in.readLine());
```

or if you are not dealing with a huge file and small memory, you can read the file in as a whole without reading lines and chunks:

```
QFile file("in.txt");
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    return;

myTextEdit.setText(file.readAll());
// or setPlainText(file.readAll());
```

These will read the data in as unicode by default based [on the documentation.](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html#QString-9)

There are several ways of doing it, so this answer is just giving you some taste, and you will need to fine-tune this based on your specific scenario. You will need to add proper error handling, includes, build system files, etc.

Comment: I tried this.But it is actually reading file data,what i need is to read unicode from file and display its corresponding text in textedit.

Comment: @QtUser: you _are_ supposed to tell in the question what you have tried. Your question is currently very poor, I am afraid. Either way, look into QString::fromUtf8.

Comment: At first, there's nothing like "simple" Unicode, but codecs based on Unicode, e.g. UTF-8, UTF-16 etc. You have to know which codec your text file use. Supposed your textfile is coded with UTF-8, you can use Laszlo's approach plus you have to set the codec in the textstream: in.setCodec("UTF-8");

Comment: @MichaelXanadu: yes, good point for encoding. QtUser, read [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtextstream.html#setCodec-2). Although [auto-detection](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtextstream.html#setAutoDetectUnicode) could be OK, too, in general.

Comment: Thanks alot for your concern .I did two points what Laszlo and MichaelXanadu said,but did not work ,then i got other addition to my code i.e i forgot to set current language to my widget QTextEdit.Now my Application works fine..So,we need to set three things 1:QString::fromUtf8 2:in.setCodec("UTF-8") 3:setCurrentLanguage(Languageofunicode); :-)

Comment: @QtUser: what do you mean by setCurrentLanguage? Which class contains that method? Also, please read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: @Laszlo Papp ,I gave clearly that this function is for QTextEdit class .And I will read whatever you suggested..

Comment: @QtUser: OK, can you provide a link to the documentation of that method? I do not see it [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtextedit-members.html).

Comment: Excuse me it is not setCurrentLanguage (),setCurrentFont() is the one i used ,